# Can't see my Entity tables in Add New Data Source…

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

HI i've trying to do simple application using Entity Framework and SQL server database. I am using that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx tutorial. Everything is perfcet untill Bind Object to Controls part. I don't see my tables in that tree structure. Do u have any ideas why? All i want to do is show data from my SQL server table, using entity framework.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: There is no my tables in the place i talked about.

Comment: Looking at the document did you create your own database or are you using an existing database. If you are using an existing database, it may be security issue. If you went though option 2 and created your own database then did you run the script to create the tables (just to confirm)